# Extending a theorem of Washington

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

In [Class numbers of the simplest cubic fields](https://doi.org/10.2307/2007897), Larry Washington states the following theorem (I have added some hypotheses to make the statement more self-contained), which is Theorem 2 in said paper:

Theorem (Washington): Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic, abelian cubic polynomial and let $E_f : y^2 = f(x)$ be the corresponding elliptic curve. Suppose that $(d,e) \in E(\mathbb{Q})$, and let

$$f(x + d) = x^3 + bx^2 + cx + e^2$$

with $b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$. Define

$$\displaystyle q_{d,e}(x) = x^4 - 2bx^3 - 8ex^2 + b^2 - 4c.$$

Let $E_f^0$ be the identity component of $E_f(\mathbb{R})$. Then the set of quartic fields $K_4(d,e)$ determined by $q_{d,e}(x)$ depends only on $(d,e) \pmod{2 E(\mathbb{Q})}$. Further, if $(d,e) \in E_f^0$ then $K_4(d,e)$ has the same discriminant as the cubic field $K = \mathbb{Q}(\theta)$, where $f(\theta) = 0$. If $(d,e) \notin E_f^0$ then $K_4(d,e)$ has discriminant equal to $64$ times that of $K$ .

Does this theorem have analogues beyond the case considered by Washington? In particular, what happens if we do not assume that $K$ is Galois?

Comment: Why don't you use pari or sage and go through a few examples?